# Gerrit SSH query - Extract commit ID from result

Tags: json, groovy, gerrit

I am trying to extract and save the commit ID for a given gerrit commit. The following command works in the sense that it provides all info about the commit:

`ssh -p <port-num> <host> gerrit query --current-patch-set <change-id>`

This command will be run from a groovy file.

It returns a result similar to the below:

```
change <change-id>
  project: <project-name>
  branch: master
  id: <change-id>
  number: 12678771
  subject: NO-JIRA
  owner:
    name: Kevin Niland
    email: <email>
    username: <username>
  url: <gerrit-url>
  commitMessage: NO-JIRA
                 
                 Change-Id: <change-id>
  createdOn: 2022-06-16 16:58:21 CEST
  lastUpdated: 2022-06-17 10:07:40 CEST
  open: true
  status: NEW
  currentPatchSet:
    number: 14
    revision: <commit-id> <--- What I want to extract
    parents:
 [dsfgdsf]
    ref: refs/changes/12/1234567/12
    uploader:
      name: Kevin Niland
      email: <email>
      username: <username>
    createdOn: 2022-06-17 10:07:39 CEST
    author:
      name: Kevin Niland
      email: <email>
      username: <username>
    isDraft: false
    kind: REWORK
    sizeInsertions: 41
    sizeDeletions: -28

type: stats
rowCount: 1
runTimeMilliseconds: 5
moreChanges: false
```

There's also the option to format the result in JSON, using `--format=JSON` which gives:

```
{"project":"project","branch":"master","id":"change-id","number":12678771,"subject":"NO-JIRA","owner":{"name":"Kevin Niland","email":"email","username":"username"},"url":"gerrit-url","commitMessage":"NO-JIRA","createdOn":1655391501,"lastUpdated":1655453260,"open":true,"status":"NEW","currentPatchSet":{"number":14,"revision":"COMMIT_ID","parents":["fgeretdsgfdghdfg"],"ref":"refs/changes/12/12345566/12","uploader":{"name":"Kevin Niland","email":"email","username":"username"},"createdOn":1655453259,"author":{"name":"Kevin Niland","email":"email","username":"username"},"isDraft":false,"kind":"REWORK","sizeInsertions":41,"sizeDeletions":-28}}
{"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":9,"moreChanges":false}
```

I am aware of the JsonSlurper library, however, I want to avoid using it, and any libraries, if possible. Is there a manual way to do this? A quick look online shows that many solutions use some library to extract info. Is there a way to extract the info from the first command, that isn't formatted in groovy?

Comment: Why avoid jsonslurper?

Answer (score 1):

Given the text above, you could use a simple regex to extract what you want:

```
String txt = '''
change <change-id>
  project: <project-name>
  id: <change-id>
  lastUpdated: 2022-06-17 10:07:40 CEST
  currentPatchSet:
    number: 14
    revision: <commit-id> <--- What I want to extract
    parents:
 '''

String revision = ( txt =~ /revision: (.+)/ ).findAll().first().last()

assert revision == '<commit-id> <--- What I want to extract'
```

If you need a more complex search, you should be using JsonSlurper to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Still baffled why they can't use a proper parser that comes as part of the language